# In pgAdmin 4, show multiple lines of a TEXT column

Tags: pgadmin, pgadmin-4

A have a TEXT column in which the values contain newlines. When I query the column in pgAdmin, I only see the first line of each value. Can I make pgAdmin show multiple lines in a cell?

Comment: I was able to get the text I wanted to see by using `replace(my_column, E'\n', ' ')`.

Comment: I'd also like to know if there's a better way to see the output. I'm trying to get json output, but I can only see the first line right now.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to the "Object Browser" panel and navigate to the table
   containing the TEXT column.
2. Right-click on the table and select "View/Edit Data" -> "All Rows".
3. In the data view, locate the TEXT column that contains the multiline
   values.
4. Right-click on the cell of the TEXT column and select "Edit Value".
5. In the "Edit Value" dialog, you'll see a checkbox labeled "Multiline
   Input". Check this checkbox to enable multiline input for the cell.
6. Once the "Multiline Input" option is enabled, you can edit and view
   the cell value with multiple lines.
7. Click "Save" to apply the changes.